# Postgresql WHERE clause adds '' around?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, pg

This morning I switched to postgresql and now my where selects dont work anymore.

What I am trying to do is super simple:

```
shirt_ids = "1,5,6" # String generated by javascript
Shirt.where("id in (?)", shirt_ids)
```

This gives me :

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1,5,6"
LINE 1: SELECT "shirts".* FROM "shirts"  WHERE (id in ('1,5,6'))
```

This works though:

```
Shirt.where("id in (#{shirt_ids})")
```

But as everybody knows is unsafe.

Im using:

```
pg (0.13.2 x86-mingw32)
rails (3.2.2)
```

Postgresql database is the newest version, I installed it this morning.

Thank you for your help.
                                                       ^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe Postgres is expecting an array, rather than a string for the IN function. If you convert your string to an array, it should work:

```
shirt_ids = "1,5,6"
Shirt.where('id in (?)', shirt_ids.split(','))
```

Also, you can do this, which looks a bit cleaner:

```
Shirt.where(:id => shirt_ids.split(','))
```

Comment: Maybe a little too quick... I realized that my original answer 'works' but actually only returns one object. Edited accordingly, this one should be fine.

Comment: More accurately, ActiveRecord sees a `?` in the SQL snippet and a String as the value, then it converts that Ruby String into the SQL string literal `'1,2,3'`. I think `shirt_ids.split(',').map(&:to_i)` would be safer.

Comment: Either way quite ugly compared to the simple `Shirt.where("id in (?)", shirt_ids)` or even simpler (I wish this would work) `Shirt.where(id: in(shirt_ids))`. I guess I will go with `Shirt.where(id: shirt_ids.split(","))`. @muistooshort Why would `.map(&:to_i)` make it safer? Doesnt postgresql automatically throw an error if some evil hacker would try to send in a string? (Which is very easy since this comes from a form)

Comment: @Stefano: The `id` values are integers and should be supplied as such, you can usually get away with using `'1'` in place of `1` but not always. If you use an array of Strings, you get `id in ('1','2','3')` when you want `id in (1,2,3)`.